# How to get Data from HTML Table

Tags: php, html, sql

I am developing a project in which I have an admin and users so in the admin panel I have a table in which all videos and All User are listed With checkBox.

In the table, I have Two columns Videos and Users. In videos column, all videos are listed and in the Users column, there is another table called Select User where all users are listed with a checkbox for each video.

So the problem is when admin selects the user's checkbox I want to know for which video he selects the users so that specific video only appear to selected users in the user panel.

image link for user table 
link: https://ibb.co/t25kppy

I hope you all understand my problem

I am able to the selected user's name from checkbox but don't know how to get the video for which the users are selected

```
<?php
require_once 'Header.php';
require_once 'Includes/DB.php';
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `videos`;';
$query2 = 'SELECT `FullName` FROM `users`;';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
$checkResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$checkResult2 = mysqli_num_rows($result2);
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
    $data[] = $row2['FullName'];

?>



<main>
<div class="container">

      <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col"><h4 align="center">Videos</h4></th>
            <th scope="col"><h4 align="center">Users</h4></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        if ($checkResult > 0 && $checkResult2 > 0)
        {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                   echo '
                  <tr>
                  <form action="Select_Users.php" method="post">
                  <td align="center" scope="row"> <iframe width="200" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $row['youtube_video_id'] . '"frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                          <th scope="col"><h4 align="left">Select Users</h4></th>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>';
                                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++)
                                    {
                                        echo '<div><label><input type="checkbox" name="selectedUsers[]" value="' . $data[$i] . ' ">' . $data[$i] . '</label></div> <br><br>';
                                    }
                                        echo'
                                    <button type="submit" name="Submit"> Submit</button>
                                </td>
                  </form>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'no result fount in database';
        }
        ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>
</div>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    if (!empty($_POST['selectedUsers']))
    {
        foreach ($_POST['selectedUsers'] as $selectedUsers)
        {
            echo '<h1>'.$row['youtube_video_id'].'</h1>';
            echo '<h1>'.$selectedUsers.'</h1>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<h1>No value found</h1>' ;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send the video id using query parameters:

```
<form action="Select_Users.php?youtube_id='.$row['youtube_video_id'].'" method="post">
```

Then retrieve it like so:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    if (!empty($_POST['selectedUsers']))
    {
        foreach ($_POST['selectedUsers'] as $selectedUsers)
        {
            $youtube_id = $_GET['youtube_id'];
            echo '<h1>'.$youtube_id.'</h1>';
            echo '<h1>'.$selectedUsers.'</h1>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<h1>No value found</h1>' ;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a hidden input with the video id in each form, name that input so that you can read the value from $_POST, just like what you did with the users.